# google chrome or firebug developer tools for find working javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, firebug

[image]
I am using google chrome developer tools to find which javscript file and which function worked. I click a button, this button changes the div size. Which javascript code do this? Is this possible? You can say firebug solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

when you "inspect element" you can see "event listeners" at right side of "developer tools" but that only shows which functions will call on this event.